# search data and export to csv codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I just created function to export data to csv file and it works great. But now, I have to search the data first and show the result on the view and then export it as csv file.

For example, I search company by the location in Kuala Lumpur then it will show companies located in Kuala Lumpur. And then I have a button to export it as csv file, but I can't figure out how to get the data from view. Is there any logic to do this one? As far, here are my model:

```
function select_company_query() {
        $sql = 'select tb_company.id as company_id, tb_company.company_name, tb_company.sector, tb_company.phone, tb_company.email, '
                . 'tb_location.id as id_location, tb_location.prefer_location from tb_company, tb_location '
                . 'where tb_company.id = tb_location.company_id';

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query;
    }
```

And my controller are:

```
function export($search_by, $search_field) {
        $this->load->dbutil();
        $this->load->helper('file');
        $path = '/var/www/company.csv';
        if ($search_by == 'FALSE') {
            $report = $this->company_model->select_company_query();

            $new_report = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($report);

            if (!write_file($path, $new_report, 'c+')) {
                echo 'Unable to write the file!';
            } else {
                redirect(base_url('index.php/company'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: no you do not need to get the data from view, actually you need to get data from model by using your query. First when you search the data from view then store the search value at any storage or get the data by using jquery and send the data by url on button click to the controller. Now you can get the search value from url and send to model and in model you can use in where clause `LIKE %Kuala Lumpur%`

Comment: could you give the example to store the search value, please?

Comment: First assign the id to your export_csv button and then in your view use script like `<script>
 $('#new_button_export_csv').click( 
 function ()
 {
  var search_val = ('#search_text_box').val() ;
  var URL = your_url+'?search_val='+search_val;
                window.location.href = URL ;
          }
</script>`

Comment: I rarely use jquery, actually. I'm a little bit confuse about that. When the search button is clicked, the search value will saved to the script right? How to do that, sir?

Comment: there will be a text box where u enter the value to search, am i right?

Comment: yes, sir. you right..

Comment: when u click on search button then in the text box value remains same ok and you can see on the script we are fetching the value by using `var search_val = $('#search_text_box').val() ; ` on export_csv click `$('#new_button_export_csv').click( function () { ...`

Comment: sorry its by mistaken `$` is not present on the previous `var search_val = ('#search_text_box').val() ; ` code. I have corrected it on the last comment

Comment: So the search value will automatically called in var search_val = ('#search_text_box').val() ;. Is it? Thank you, sir. I'll try first..

Comment: use `var search_val = $('#search_text_box').val() ;`

Comment: you can use  session to save the array

Answer (score 0):

to expoert csv data you have to include a csv_helper file 
in controller you have just to do is

$this->load->helper('csv');
    query_to_csv($query, TRUE, 'searchfile.csv');

$query is your result data